# Background Image loaded but not displaying

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm probably being idiotic here. I've been trying to get a jpeg image to load in the background of a section element as part of a bootstrap course I'm doing (pretty new to this web dev stuff). The image is loading fine in the firefox inspector - it shows no errors and displays the image if I hover over the link - but it just isn't displaying on the page.

Here's the relevant code:

```
<secton id="cover">
    <div id="cover-caption">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-sm-10 sm-offset-1"></div>
            <h1>Generic website title</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</secton>
```

css:

```
#cover{
    background: url("Assets/Photos/Blanket.jpg") center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
}
```

The path and name of the image is definitely correct, so it's not that.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try adding width: 50px; to test in #cover

Comment: You have a typo right at the beginning: `<secton>`

Comment: Yeah, the inspector might render because it is working of the stuff internal to the broken tag...

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it! As expected, immediately after posting.

Apparently setting the height to 100% was the issue. Changing it to 100vmin made all the difference.

Baby steps...